# Perl - Pattern contains new line

Tags: perl

I am trying to grab all functions from a C file in a perl script.

Pattern example :

```
function return type  
function name (function parameters)  
{
```

So far I have: `m/^(.*)\((.*)\)/`

But this grabs functions inside as well, such as `if` statements, so I was hoping to match for the `{` as well since that would eliminate all internal functions but `m/^(.*)\((.*)\)/\n\{/`
doesn't work.

How do I match for the `\n{` *i.e* the `{` in the next line, so that I can catch

```
add(int a, int b)  
{
```

... but avoid, say

```
if(a = b)
```

Comment: I don't think it will be very reliable to use `\n` in your program to analyze the input data. Remember in C you can easily have a one-liner function, or even two on the same line.

Comment: @mogul actually i want to match for the { in the next line, to grab functions that are being defined rather than functions that are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no asterisks you want to match in the C source. Therefore, remove the backslashes before asterisks in the pattern.

The following might be closer to what you want:

```
m/^(.*?\(.*?\))\s*\n{/m
```

Comment: oh sorry that was more a failure to copy my code to here from my system. To clarify my problem is that i want to match for the { in the next line.

Comment: I tried your regex and it doesn't seem to hit on my sample code.. also what does "\s*" do exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [C::Scan](http://search.cpan.org/~hvds/C-Scan-0.74/Scan.pm) over at CPAN